# FullCalendar not refreshing events on button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to fetch events from database and append on Full Calendar. To accomplish this, i used a dropdown list for months and year. On selection of month from downdown list and clicking on search button, the events are appended to the calendar. But when i try to change the month from the dropdown and later click on the search button, the selected data is rightly fetched from the database but keeps the old events and doesn't refresh the new month events. Below is my code.

**EventCalendar.aspx**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#searchBtn").click(function () {

           var month = $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_DropDownMonth option:selected').val();
           var user = $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_DDUser option:selected').val();
           alert(month.split(" ")[0]);
           var monthname = month.split(" ")[0];
           var year = month.split(" ")[1];

           var monthd = new Date(Date.parse(monthname + "1", year)).getMonth() + 1
           var date = year + "-" + monthd + "-" + "1"
           console.log(monthd)

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "NewUserScore.aspx/GetScoreDetails",
                    data: "{ 'userId':'" + user + "', 'month':'" + month + "'}",

                    success: function (result) {

                        events_array = [];

                        $.each(result.d, function (key, value)
                        {
                            if (value.start != null) {
                                events_array.push(
                                {
                                    title: value.title,
                                    start: value.start
                                });
                            }
                       });

                        console.log(events_array)



                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                                theme: true,

                                header: {
                                    left: 'prev,next today',
                                    center: 'title',
                                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                                },

                                defaultDate: date,
                                displayEventTime: false,
                                events: events_array,


                                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {


                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        url: "NewUserScore.aspx/GetScoreDetailsForDate",
                                        data: "{ 'date':'" + date.format() + "', 'userId':'" + user + "'}",
                                        success: function (result) {

                                            $("#tblScore td").remove();

                                            var tblEmployee = $("#tblScore");

                                            $.each(result.d, function (index, item) {

                                                var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

                                                tr.html(("<td> <button type=\"button\" id=" + item.Id + "  class=\"btnEdit\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#dialog-transaction\">Edit</button> </td>")
                                                + " " + ("<td><button type=\"button\" id=" + item.Id + "  class=\"btnDelete\">Delete</button></td>")
                                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.scoreDate + "</td>")
                                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.uUser.struserName + "</td>")
                                                + " " + ("<td><a href =\"Case.aspx?id=" + item.cCase.strId + "\" target=_blank>" + item.cCase.strTitle + "</a> </td>")
                                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.pProject.strProjName + "</td>")
                                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.CaseScore + "</td>"));

                                                tblEmployee.append(tr);

                                            });
                                         }
                                    });
                                },


                            });

                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                     }
                });
        });
    });



</script>
```

**--Update--**

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function () {

           var month = $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_DropDownMonth option:selected').val();
           var user = $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_DDUser option:selected').val();
           alert(month.split(" ")[0]);
           var monthname = month.split(" ")[0];
           var year = month.split(" ")[1];

           var monthd = new Date(Date.parse(monthname + "1", year)).getMonth() + 1
           var date = year + "-" + monthd + "-" + "1"
           console.log(monthd)


                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "NewUserScore.aspx/GetScoreDetails",
                    data: "{ 'userId':'" + user + "', 'month':'" + month + "'}",

                    success: function (result) {

                        events = [];

                        $.each(result.d, function (key, value)
                        {
                            if (value.start != null) {
                                events.push(
                                {
                                    title: value.title,
                                    start: value.start
                                });
                            }
                       });

                        console.log(events)

                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents', events);
                    }
                });
        });


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },


                displayEventTime: false,
                //events: events_array,


                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "NewUserScore.aspx/GetScoreDetailsForDate",
                        data: "{ 'date':'" + date.format() + "', 'userId':'" + user + "'}",
                        success: function (result) {

                            $("#tblScore td").remove();

                            var tblEmployee = $("#tblScore");

                            $.each(result.d, function (index, item) {

                                var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

                                tr.html(("<td> <button type=\"button\" id=" + item.Id + "  class=\"btnEdit\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#dialog-transaction\">Edit</button> </td>")
                                + " " + ("<td><button type=\"button\" id=" + item.Id + "  class=\"btnDelete\">Delete</button></td>")
                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.scoreDate + "</td>")
                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.uUser.struserName + "</td>")
                                + " " + ("<td><a href =\"Case.aspx?id=" + item.cCase.strId + "\" target=_blank>" + item.cCase.strTitle + "</a> </td>")
                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.pProject.strProjName + "</td>")
                                + " " + ("<td>" + item.CaseScore + "</td>"));

                                tblEmployee.append(tr);

                            });
                        }
                    });
                },

            });
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
      });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you add complete view source of page and JSON object return by api "NewUserScore.aspx/GetScoreDetailsForDate"

Comment: But that's a different case. Its just for populating data in a separate table and not on the full calendar. The actual ajax call for events is "NewUserScore.aspx/GetScoreDetails"

Comment: you don't need to, and shouldn't, re-initialise your calendar every time the search is pressed, all you need to do is re-fetch the events but passing a different parameter value for the search. Declare your calendar _once_ outside the "Search" button callback, but set your events to be a dynamic callback function - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . Then when you click the search button, the only thing you need to do is run "refetchEvents". fullCalendar will automatically execute your "events" callback and fetch new data from the server, without re-creating the whole calendar

Comment: @ADyson From your comments, what my understanding is, I should pass the collected event data to re-fetch event like this:  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents', events) but the events are not visible and the month that i choose from dropdown doesn't load the calendar month. It always loads the default month. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @ADyson By the way  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); did the trick which i wanted but i do want to apply functionality for re-fetching event if in case if want to use backward and forward button.

Comment: ", I should pass the collected event data to re-fetch event like this: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents', events)". No, refetchEvents doens't accept any events as a parameter. Instead, if you set `events` as a _function_ (as per the page I linked you to), running refetchEvents will cause that function to execute again. Inside that function will be your ajax call to return the events. At that moment, you can easily pass to the ajax call the current values in the search field